# How to schedule SQL queries based on .sql file name?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sqlcmd

I am now working on an automation for marketing that:

1. Refill the campaign information based on marketing needs in a shared
   file
2. Generate SQL codes based on this shared file and export the queries to a certain folder
3. Run the queries on the dates specified in the shared file.

What I have automated:

1. Created an excel file to generate & export SQL codes according to
   input;
2. Union all the queries that need to run on the date today to one file named after "**SQLtoRunToday.sql**" and export to a shared directory, this file will be replaced by a new one every day.

What I need to do now:
To automatically run **SQLtoRunToday.sql** daily at early morning.

I have tried to use SQL cmd command, however, I just realize that if the computer is off, the command schedule will not run, however, I cannot keep my computer always on.

I have tried also to create a job in SQL server, however, the job cannot take the updated SQL, it sticks to the original one when I configure it.

Do you have any idea how can I make this happen?

Comment: You should be able to edit the SQL in the job.   If you cannot, you are either doing it wrong, or you lack the necessary permission.   Can you add a screenshot of your attempt to edit the job?

Comment: If your computer is off, how will you run the SQL job? Something seems off here. Why is your database server off in the middle of the night when you need to run a script? I don't think anyone can solve that for you.

Comment: @JacobH i assumed the script was on OP machine and server elsewhere. 
 In which case the script and schedule should be on the main server, not OP machine. Anyhow, my work machine only gets turned off when there's a powercut.

Comment: @Tanner Ah I misunderstood. The USERs machine is off, not the server.

Comment: @JacobH that may not be fact, that was my assumption.

Comment: _I have tried also to create a job in SQL server, however, the job cannot take the updated sql, it sticks to the original one when I configure it. _

And how exactly did you did you define this job? It should have been a simple sqlcmd command step.

Comment: @SMor I was wondering the same thing. What does "the job cannot take the updated SQL" mean? Sounds like user error, not a sql problem.

Comment: Yes as assumed by @Tanner, I am working on the User computer and using a remote server to run queries. As I am not working for BI team, I don't have the access to put the script & schedule in the main server. I am only doing this for automating small queries for marketing needs.

Comment: @Jacob I am sorry I didn't make it clear. I meant that it doesn't automatically take into account when the SQL gets updated in the SQLtoRunToday.sql.  As I mentioned, this file actually updates itself daily & replace the SQL script of the previous day. I would avoid re-configure it or manually update the job when the query changes.

Comment: Instead of using the T-SQL script step, set up a SQL Agent job with a PowerShell script to run your SQL file from the folder. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/powershell/invoke-sqlcmd-cmdlet

Answer (score 0):

One approach would be to use a batch file, and dynamically determine the file name within a stored procedure. The SP can be scheduled. Something like this:

exec xp_cmdshell 'c:\dbajob\mybatch.bat'

You can also fill a temp table with the contents of a file, like this:

CREATE TABLE #MyFile (MyText VARCHAR(500))

BULK INSERT #MyFile
FROM 'L:\temp\PipeTest.txt'

In that approach, you can pull the contents of your SQL file into a table, then iterate and run.

Answer (score 0):

While generating this sql file SQLtoRunToday.sql you can generate job dynamically as below:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION
DECLARE @ReturnCode INT
SELECT @ReturnCode = 0
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT name FROM msdb.dbo.syscategories WHERE name=N'[Uncategorized (Local)]' AND category_class=1)
BEGIN
EXEC @ReturnCode = msdb.dbo.sp_add_category @class=N'JOB', @type=N'LOCAL', @name=N'[Uncategorized (Local)]'
IF (@@ERROR <> 0 OR @ReturnCode <> 0) GOTO QuitWithRollback

END

DECLARE @jobId BINARY(16)
EXEC @ReturnCode =  msdb.dbo.sp_add_job @job_name=N'Test', 
        @enabled=1, 
        @notify_level_eventlog=0, 
        @notify_level_email=0, 
        @notify_level_netsend=0, 
        @notify_level_page=0, 
        @delete_level=0, 
        @description=N'No description available.', 
        @category_name=N'[Uncategorized (Local)]', 
        @owner_login_name=N'yourlogin', @job_id = @jobId OUTPUT
IF (@@ERROR <> 0 OR @ReturnCode <> 0) GOTO QuitWithRollback
EXEC @ReturnCode = msdb.dbo.sp_add_jobstep @job_id=@jobId, @step_name=N'Your step', 
        @step_id=1, 
        @cmdexec_success_code=0, 
        @on_success_action=1, 
        @on_success_step_id=0, 
        @on_fail_action=2, 
        @on_fail_step_id=0, 
        @retry_attempts=0, 
        @retry_interval=0, 
        @os_run_priority=0, @subsystem=N'TSQL', 
        @command=N'select 1--your query', 
        @database_name=N'yourdatabase', 
        @flags=0
IF (@@ERROR <> 0 OR @ReturnCode <> 0) GOTO QuitWithRollback
EXEC @ReturnCode = msdb.dbo.sp_update_job @job_id = @jobId, @start_step_id = 1
IF (@@ERROR <> 0 OR @ReturnCode <> 0) GOTO QuitWithRollback
EXEC @ReturnCode = msdb.dbo.sp_add_jobserver @job_id = @jobId, @server_name = N'(local)'
IF (@@ERROR <> 0 OR @ReturnCode <> 0) GOTO QuitWithRollback
COMMIT TRANSACTION
GOTO EndSave
QuitWithRollback:
    IF (@@TRANCOUNT > 0) ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
EndSave:
```

You can create appropriate schedule for that as well